# How to passing session object between Android Activities

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm working on a project which is used Dropbox Android apis to implementation the upload and download functions.
First step i used a UploadButton trigger a fileselectorActivity this function i use Intent method to implemented jump to next activity,but intent method unable to bring dropbox session to other activity (probably about the dropbox session type does not String). afer executed the file selector Activity that will selected a specific file path upload to dropbox,

I want to know how to passing the dropbox session to fileselectorActivity after selecting a target file will send to uploadActivity.
Intent method and bundle is used but not useful.
Here is my code.

MainActivity code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> dropbox;
    private final static String FILE_DIR = "/";
    private final static String DROPBOX_NAME = "dropbox_prefs";
    private final static String ACCESS_KEY = "***************";
    private final static String ACCESS_SECRET = "************";
    private String path = "/";
    private boolean isLoggedIn;
    private Button logIn;
    private Button uploadFile;
    private Button encryption;
    private Button decryption;
    private Button listFiles;

    private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
    private ListView itemlist;
    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        logIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dropbox_login);
        logIn.setOnClickListener(this);
        uploadFile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.UploadButton);
        uploadFile.setOnClickListener(this);
        decryption=(Button) findViewById(R.id.decryptionButton);
        decryption.setOnClickListener(this);
        encryption=(Button) findViewById(R.id.encryptionButton);
        encryption.setOnClickListener(this);
        listFiles = (Button) findViewById(R.id.list_files);
        listFiles.setOnClickListener(this);
        // get itemlist
        itemlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.itemList);

        // encryption();
        loggedIn(false);
        AndroidAuthSession session;
        AppKeyPair pair = new AppKeyPair(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET);

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(DROPBOX_NAME, 0);
        String key = prefs.getString(ACCESS_KEY, null);
        String secret = prefs.getString(ACCESS_SECRET, null);

        if (key != null && secret != null) {
            AccessTokenPair token = new AccessTokenPair(key, secret);
            session = new AndroidAuthSession(pair, AccessType.DROPBOX, token);
        } else {
            session = new AndroidAuthSession(pair, AccessType.DROPBOX);
        }
        dropbox = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        AndroidAuthSession session = dropbox.getSession();
        if (session.authenticationSuccessful()) {
            try {
                session.finishAuthentication();
                TokenPair tokens = session.getAccessTokenPair();
                SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(DROPBOX_NAME, 0);
                Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putString(ACCESS_KEY, tokens.key);
                editor.putString(ACCESS_SECRET, tokens.secret);
                editor.commit();
                loggedIn(true);
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error during Dropbox authentication",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    public void loggedIn(boolean isLogged) {
        isLoggedIn = isLogged;
        uploadFile.setEnabled(isLogged);
        listFiles.setEnabled(isLogged);
        decryption.setEnabled(isLogged);
        encryption.setEnabled(isLogged);
        logIn.setText(isLogged ? "Log out" : "Log in");
    }

    private final Handler handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            items.clear();
            ArrayList<String> result = msg.getData().getStringArrayList("data");
            for (String fileName : result) {
                items.add(fileName);
            }
            handleitems();
        }

    };

    public void handleitems() {
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, items);
        itemlist.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        itemlist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                String item = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                DownloadFileFromDropbox download2=new DownloadFileFromDropbox(parent.getContext(), dropbox, path,item);
                download2.execute();
            }

        });
    }



    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.dropbox_login:
            if (isLoggedIn) {
                dropbox.getSession().unlink();
                loggedIn(false);
            } else {
                dropbox.getSession().startAuthentication(MainActivity.this);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.list_files:
            ListDropboxFiles list = new ListDropboxFiles(dropbox, FILE_DIR,handler);
            list.execute();
            break;
        case R.id.UploadButton:
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FileChooser.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        //  UploadFileToDropbox uploader=new UploadFileToDropbox(this, dropbox, path);
        //  uploader.execute();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }


}
```

Fileselector code.

```
package filechooser;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI;
import com.dropbox.client2.android.AndroidAuthSession;
import com.dropbox.client2.exception.DropboxException;
import com.dropbox.client2.exception.DropboxUnlinkedException;
import com.example.ik2000dropbox.MainActivity;
import com.example.ik2000dropbox.R;
import com.example.ik2000dropbox.UploadFileToDropbox;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FileChooser extends ListActivity {

    private File currentDir;
    FileArrayAdapter adapter;



    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        currentDir = new File("/sdcard/download");
        fill(currentDir);
    }

    private void fill(File f) {
        File[] dirs = f.listFiles();
        this.setTitle("Current Dir: " + f.getName());
        List<Option> dir = new ArrayList<Option>();
        List<Option> fls = new ArrayList<Option>();
        try {
            for (File ff : dirs) {
                if (ff.isDirectory())
                    dir.add(new Option(ff.getName(), "Folder", ff
                            .getAbsolutePath()));
                else {
                    fls.add(new Option(ff.getName(), "File Size: "
                            + ff.length(), ff.getAbsolutePath()));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        Collections.sort(dir);
        Collections.sort(fls);
        dir.addAll(fls);
        if (!f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("sdcard"))
            dir.add(0, new Option("..", "Parent Directory", f.getParent()));
        adapter = new FileArrayAdapter(FileChooser.this, R.layout.file_view,dir);
        this.setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Option o = adapter.getItem(position);
        if (o.getData().equalsIgnoreCase("folder")
                || o.getData().equalsIgnoreCase("parent directory")) {
            currentDir = new File(o.getPath());
            fill(currentDir);
        } else {

            onFileClick(o);
        }
    }

    private void onFileClick(Option o) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "File Clicked: " + o.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```

My upload Activity

```
public class UploadFileToDropbox  extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private DropboxAPI<?> dropbox;
    private String path;
    private Context context;

    public UploadFileToDropbox(Context context, DropboxAPI<?> dropbox,
            String path) {
        this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
        this.dropbox = dropbox;
        this.path = path;
    }



    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
        File file = new File("/sdcard/download/lecture.pdf.p7m");
        FileInputStream inputStream =new FileInputStream(file);
        dropbox.putFile(path + "lecture.pdf.p7m",inputStream,
                file.length(), null, null);
        return true;    

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DropboxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return false;
    }





    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if (result) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "File Uploaded Sucesfully!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to upload file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: AndroidAuthSession should implement serializable or parcelable. try to use parcelable it more efficient. post your AndroidAuthSession object

Comment: I already get that session ,now the problem is i want know how to send this session to other activity.i used intent.putExtra("session",dropbox);  but this does not work.

Comment: yup , to pass objects with intent it must implement serializable or parcelable

Comment: does this way is correct ?bundle.putSerializable("sessionID", (Serializable) dropbox); my eclipse shows" Parcel: unable to marshal value com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI@41180f30"

Comment: nope, AndroidAuthSession must implement it . post your AndroidAuthSession and i will submit the solution as answer

Comment: I prefer stackoverflow ,update your post with the class and I can post the changes or follow this link 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Comment: Hi,r7v i have posted my activity code and fileselector code,could you help me post the solution? thank you so much

Comment: cool, so what are you trying to pass here to the acitivty

Comment: To passing the argument "dropbox" from the MainActivity to the FileChooserActivity.

Comment: seems AndroidAuthSession is part of dropbox api

Comment: alright , as the session would be used across the app initialize it in the application class and access it across activities

Comment: Yes please check my post code again,i posted uploadActivity,if in mainActivity i direct use  // UploadFileToDropbox uploader=new UploadFileToDropbox(this, dropbox, path);
  // uploader.execute();    this will be work fine,but then will without fileselectorActivity .

Answer (score 1):

Create Application Object

```
 public class MyApplication extends Application implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks{

            private final static String ACCESS_KEY = "***************";
            private final static String ACCESS_SECRET = "************";

            private  static MyApplication singleton;
            private DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> dropbox;

            private final static String DROPBOX_NAME = "dropbox_prefs";

            public DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> getDropbox() {
                return dropbox;
            }

            public void setDropbox(DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> dropbox) {
                this.dropbox = dropbox;
            }



            @Override
            public void onCreate() {
                super.onCreate();
                singleton = this;
                SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(DROPBOX_NAME, 0);
                String key = prefs.getString(ACCESS_KEY, null);
                String secret = prefs.getString(ACCESS_SECRET, null);

                if (key != null && secret != null) {
                    AccessTokenPair token = new AccessTokenPair(key, secret);
                    session = new AndroidAuthSession(pair, AccessType.DROPBOX, token);
                } else {
                    session = new AndroidAuthSession(pair, AccessType.DROPBOX);
                }
                dropbox = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);
            }}
```

Add it to manifest

```
  <application
            android:name=".MyApplication"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Use in activity

```
   MyApplication.getInstance().getDropbox()
```

Comment: Great !! please accept the answer if this was the right one

Answer (score 0):

```
Create Application Object

 public class MyApplication extends Application implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks{

            private final static String ACCESS_KEY = "***************";
            private final static String ACCESS_SECRET = "************";

            private  static MyApplication singleton;
            private DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> dropbox;

            private final static String DROPBOX_NAME = "dropbox_prefs";

            public DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> getDropbox() {
                return dropbox;
            }

            public void setDropbox(DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> dropbox) {
                this.dropbox = dropbox;
            }



            @Override
            public void onCreate() {
                super.onCreate();
                singleton = this;
                SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(DROPBOX_NAME, 0);
                String key = prefs.getString(ACCESS_KEY, null);
                String secret = prefs.getString(ACCESS_SECRET, null);

                if (key != null && secret != null) {
                    AccessTokenPair token = new AccessTokenPair(key, secret);
                    session = new AndroidAuthSession(pair, AccessType.DROPBOX, token);
                } else {
                    session = new AndroidAuthSession(pair, AccessType.DROPBOX);
                }
                dropbox = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);
            }}
Add it to manifest

  <application
            android:name=".MyApplication"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
Use in activity

   MyApplication.getInstance().getDropbox()
```